# I installed linux and replace with window 7 ? how to recover drives data back

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, ntfs, data-recovery

i just installed LINUX in my laptop.i had window 7 , i replace UBUNTU with window 7. the drives data(D:, E:) in window is not showing in LINUX. how to recover my drives data. i didn't use LINUX yet. how to get my data back.in this(LINUX) it shows 490 GB free. my Hard disk is 500 GB.how to get back my 150 GB data now. Please describe me the way to get all the deleted data.please help me.i need your suggestion.thanks a lot for helping me.

Comment: Since you've not just formatted the partition but also written data to it (installed Ubuntu) it's likely that you'd lose some of your data that have been overwritten. Remember, the more newer files you save to the partition the more data will be overwritten and the lesser will be there for you to recover. So now you should be looking to use the Data Recovery Tools to get back those that are still to be overwritten. These could help you:http://ubuntu-rescue-remix.org/, http://www.knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html

Answer (score 0):

Log in into Ubuntu , then press **Ctrl+Alt+t** for opening **terminal** , or press **Super** key thats known as Windows key in windows to open **dash** , and search **terminal**, clcik on it .

Then paste the following command into **terminal** and hit **ENTER**  -

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

After its Installed , search for it in **Dash** by pressing **super** key , Click on it and then **close**  , give a soft **reboot** by entering following in **terminal** and hit **enter**-

```
sudo reboot
```

After reboot hopefully you will be able to see the other partitions , if they are not formatted or deleted due to any circumstance.

Gparted will show the current usage and status of the Partitions.

Comment: how ?? sorry to say .. i am new in linux.. even i am not know how to install .what can i do with " sudo apt-get install gparted  "? please give me step by step information

Comment: wait I am updating my answer

Comment: sure ... so nice ....:)